# Tacx QR Skewer Alterantives

Tags: replacement, skewer

So my LBS managed to lose my Tacx blue matic skewer when I asked them to service my wheel. They gave me a replacement one from decathlon, but it's too small and the bike wobbles on the trainer.

I've been getting it to hold in place by stuffing tissue inside, but that's not really a long term solution.

I've scoured the internet high and low to find a replacement skewer, but they are sold out the world over.

I was wondering if there are any other brands of skewer that would fit the same as the original one. TIA!

Edit - I should say that it's not too small, but rather the shape is incorrect. The original skewer has cylindrical ends, but the decathlon one I was given has tapered ends and doesn't fit well on the trainer.

Comment: Tacx do a 12mm and 10mm skewer, What aside did the LBS give you ? I’d take it back and ask them for the proper Tacx one, even more so as they’re designed to fit in the clamps on the trainer

Comment: I did, but no one can get one at the moment so I was hoping that a skewer from a different brand might work.

Answer (score 4):

Garmin is the vendor for the Tacx brand.
Although the Tacx Blue trainer has been discontinued, Garmin still sells other trainers and offers a "[universal quick release](https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/p/707018/pn/T1402#devices)" part number T1402 on their website. The Tacx Blue listed as a compatible device.

The compatible devices include the Boost trainer, Flow, FLUX 2, Flux S, Neo 2, Neo 2T and Satori Smart Trainers so it would make sense that any skewer for any of those devices would fit your trainer.

[image]

This part is very different than a normal skewer due to it's length and large round ends designed to fit well into the trainer.

Comment: Unfortunately they won't have stock for a couple of months and I'm in Taiwan and they don't deliver to Taiwan from the US site.

Comment: @StuartDawson I've found the skewer on ebay. Not sure if that helps your shipping situation. Search for TACX T1402

Answer (score -5):

I don't think a quick release skewer can be "too small". All quick release skewers have the same skewer diameter, to fit in quick release axles. The only variation is in the length of the quick release skewer, and that's dependent on the hub width.

I'm not familiar with trainers but I suspect they have an interface that mimics a wheel. If a trainer is to be used with quick release, you should be able to use any quick release of the proper length.

There are differences in the quality of quick release skewers, however. [Internal cam is superior to external cam](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/skewers.html). The external cam ones have far less clamping force. Neither type of quick release is suitable for use with front disc brake wheels because they cannot provide enough force to retain the wheel in the dropouts.

I suppose the replacement skewer is a "boutique" external cam non-Shimano quick release skewer. Throw that away and replace it with a quality Shimano internal cam unit. And when installing the Shimano unit, rotate the end so much that it has enough clamping force. The quick releases have an adjustable tension and if that's adjusted too low, it won't work well.

Comment: "I'm not familiar with trainers but..." Perhaps asking for clarification would be appropriate?